# Is it acceptable to mix stored procedures with Linq using Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and writing one of my first applications using Entity Framework. There are some quite complicated SQL queries and I'm finding it much easier to just write a stored procedure rather than try to do it in Linq.

Is it an acceptable practice in the industry to mix Linq and stored procedures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its perfectly acceptable.

Entity Framework is very powerful and has its place. But there are times where the control and readability/maintainability a stored procedure gives you, can provide a better solution.

I would suggest your goal is to use the right tool for the job.

Maybe describing the problem you are trying to solve and what you have attempted and we can suggest alternate ways.

Comment: +1 - absolutely. EF is great for fairly simple & straightforward handling of single or a handful or rows, while "raw" SQL excels at handling complex situations and bulk operations.